# gitorious work with more than one repository

Tags: git, gitorious

I'm a member of an developer team at gitorious. But to work on bigger features I cloned the repository (on gitorious not locally). So now there are two gitorious projects, "project" (the original repository) and "my-project" (my server-side clone).

Now my question is: What's the best way to work with these two repositories? Of course I can clone both of them locally in two different directories and work in on or the other directory. But them merging back my changes could be quite complicated. Probably I would have to initiate a merge request at one side and accept it at the other side.

Something what I would like to have, no idea if this is possible: Create a local clone of the main project and integrate "my-project" locally as a branch or something similar so that I can easily switch between both repositories, cherry-pick from one to the other, etc.

Is something like this possible? Or what is the best way to work with more then one (server-side) clone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `git remote add` to add the second remote to your local repository. These commands would add your server-side gitorious clone as a remote called "personal", and fetch branch refs from it:

```
git remote add personal <path_to_server_side_clone>
git fetch personal
```

You don't even to use different branches. In practice, your history will look something like this during the workday (simplified for just a single branch):

```
  origin/master
        |
A-B-C-D-E-F-G master
      |
personal/master
```

In the above diagram, `origin`'s master branch points to commit `E`, `personal`'s points to `D`, and your local `master`'s branch tip is `G`. Suppose `origin`'s stability is quite important, i.e. you only push to it after it passes a test suite on your machine. You still want to save your daily work, yes? That's exactly the purpose of your `personal` repository. `git push personal master` changes the diagram like so:

```
  origin/master
        |
A-B-C-D-E-F-G master
            |
     personal/master
```

The `personal` remote's `master` and your local copy of `master` are now in sync. After you run your test suite, you then issue `git push origin master`, yielding this state:

```
      origin/master
            |
A-B-C-D-E-F-G master
            |
     personal/master
```

In practice, you can push any set of branches to either remote, share between them, or opt to keep one clean and one full of half-finished topic branches. It's up to you. I do recommend using history visualization software like `tig` or `gitk`, both of which make visualizing where your remote states easy.

You can take this idea as far as you'd like. At work, I've a remote for every one of my coworkers (we also use gitorious), all of whom have personal server-side clones. It's a brilliantly easy way to share code while still maintaining a [blessed production repository.](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows#Integration-Manager-Workflow) Nearly any workflow can benefit from personal remote clones.